Power BI RTSP video streaming using HTML viewer visualization
I have a CCTV rtsp video and I want to stream it in Power BI Dashboard using html5 viewer visualization which I need to put a HTML script as its data.
The data is like this:



location
video_url
html_script




Lobby
"rtsp://admin:adminpass@1.1.1.1:554/Streaming/Channels/1"
?????


Pantry
"rtsp://admin:adminpass@1.1.1.1:554/Streaming/Channels/1"
?????



What is the correct html script?
Or, if it is possible to do stream live video on power bi at the first place?
I use the script like this
<video width = "100%" controls><source src = "rtsp://admin:adminapass@1.1.1.1:554/Streaming/Channels/1/" autoplay = "autoplay" type="video/mp4">


but it didn't work... even though the video works just fine when I online stream using VLC

Videos (and other external content) will not display in PBI Desktop (currently). You will need to publish the report and view it online for the content to load.
